# Стили для колонок таблицы

Tags: html, css

Создается такая таблица

```
<table class="char">
    <col id="param1" />
    <col id="dimension1" />
    <col id="param2" />
    <col id="dimension2" />
    <tr>
        <td><span>Дата</span></td>
        <td><span>10.08.2009</span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><span>Объектов</span></td>
        <td><span>10</span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

К ней таблица стилей

```
table.char {
    border: none;
}

#param1 {
    width: 40mm;
}

#dimension1 {
    width: 40mm;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#param2 {
    width: 35mm;
}

#dimension2 {
    width: 40mm;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

не понимаю, почему параметр width для колонок таблицы отрабатывает, при изменении значения ширина колонки меняется, а font-weight - нет.
Подскажите?

Answer (score 3):

У тега `col` имеется только атрибуты: align, char, charoff, span, valign, width... а font-weight нет. Надо или к `td` или `tr` применять font-weight. (Точнее tr или td ставить класс и к классу уже применять `font-weight`).

Информация тут: [`тег <col>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/col).

```
<table class="char">
    <col id="dimension1" />
    <col id="dimension2" />
    <tr id="dimension1">
        <td><span>Дата</span></td>
        <td><span>10.08.2009</span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr id="dimension2">
        <td><span>Объектов</span></td>
        <td><span>10</span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>    
</table>​
```

-

```
table.char {
    border: none;
}

#dimension1 {
    width: 40mm;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#dimension2 {
    width: 40mm;
}​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jkwe45/VHxFA/1/embedded/result/

Comment: мне нужно задать разную насыщенность шрифта не по строкам, а по столбцам, но прописывать класс у каждого тега <td> не хочется, это слишком загромоздит код. а что касается атрибутов, то вы путаете атрибуты тегов и css-свойства, у тега <table> атрибута border-collapse, например, ведь нет, но вы же задаете это свойство через css, верно?

Comment: а вообще, вы правы, с помощью элемента col можно задать только ширину столбца таблицы (((

Comment: верно, но могу предположить, что максимум, что можно - проставить id в ячейках одного нужного столбца

Comment: ну только тогда уже не id, а class

Comment: загнался) да, class

Answer (score 2):

Если в таблице нет разных colspan'ов в разных строках, то можно использовать:

```
td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(4) {font-weight:bold}
```

или покороче, для каждой второй колонки:

```
td:nth-child(2n) {font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: не, это верно, но сss3 использовать бы не хотелось.

Comment: [CSS - Table columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html)

> The spec says that other CSS declarations may not be set on columns. The spec is wrong here; there is no harm in setting them. They should be overruled by styles on trs or tds, of course.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в конечном итоге проблему решила с помощью jQuery, так как с использованием её псевдокласс `:nth-child` поддерживает даже ie

```
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("table.char td:nth-child(2n)").css({
            "font-weight": "bold"
        });

        jQuery("table.char td:eq(0), table.char td:eq(1), table.char td:eq(3)").css({
            "width": "40mm"
        });

        jQuery("table.char td:eq(2)").css({
            "width": "35mm"
        });
    });
</script>
```